# Can I transition from Ortho to Perspective camera?

Tags: camera, orthographic

I'm preparing for a short animation for this week. I would need to start the animation using an Orthographic Camera and then transition to a Perspective camera. Is it possible in Blender and how to do this? Or should I cheat and use a really long focal length and shorten it to achieve a similar effect?

I have a flat logo, comprising of a black circular background and a few white circular "stars" on top. The stars are connected. It looks like a little network icon. I want the logo to "become" 3D, by transitioning it from full to no opacity, and at the same time transitioning the opacity on a 3D duplicate of this network. So it sort of comes out of the logo. That's when I need to transition from Orthographic to Perspective. It needs to be orthographic in the beginning because it needs to line up with the logo. Then once it "comes out" it can be a regular 3D perspective.

So, does it make sense, is this possible to do?

Comment: I would suggest that instead of altering the camera you alter the logo from 2d to 3d. So that you start with a flat logo and make it 3D by using shapekeys, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAr29.gif

Comment: @cegaton, this is awesome, I think I'll try this approach first